# PCL EuclideanClusterExtraction Segfault in Fuerte

Tags: pcl, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there.

So I just moved from electric to fuerte and now I get a seg fault when using PCL (1.5). I am trying to cluster a point cloud to identify some objects (basic tabletop scenario), and I keep getting the same seg fault issue mentioned here:

http://dev.pointclouds.org/issues/673

Can anyone tell me how I can maybe upgrade to a newer PCL version where this bug was solved and use it with ROS fuerte? Thanks a lot.

Nichola

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41344/pcl-euclideanclusterextraction-segfault-in-fuerte/) by [Nichola](https://answers.ros.org/users/3028/nichola/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-08-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could try the solution posted here: http://answers.ros.org/question/39946/upgrading-to-pcl-160-with-ros-fuerte-ubuntu-1204/?answer=39958#post-id-39958

This uses the unstable pcl16 ROS package. This package can coexist with the other PCL, and everything is just put into the pcl16 namespace.

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1